# typeof(t).GetProperties() when t is an interface that derives from another one

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

why typeof(t).GetProperties() does not find all the public properties of t when t is a derived interface? Is this the expected behavior or I am missing something?

```
public interface IBaseOne
    {        int Id { get; }    }

public interface IDerivedOne : IBaseOne
    {        string Name { get; }    }

public class ImplementsIDerivedOne : IDerivedOne
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

public static class TypeOfTests
    {
        public static Type Testing<T>() where T : class,IBaseOne
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type typeFromIBaseOne = TypeOfTests.Testing<IBaseOne  >() ;
        Type typeFromIDerivedOne = TypeOfTests.Testing<IDerivedOne>();
        Type typeFromImplementsIDerivedOne = TypeOfTests.Testing<ImplementsIDerivedOne>();

        PropertyInfo[] propsFromIBaseOne = typeFromIBaseOne.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] propsFromIDerivedOne = typeFromIDerivedOne.GetProperties();
        PropertyInfo[] propsFromImplementsIDerivedOne =TypeFromImplementsIDerivedOne.GetProperties();

        Debug.Print("From IBaseOne: {0} properties", propsFromIBaseOne.Length);
        Debug.Print("From IDerivedOne: {0} properties", propsFromIDerivedOne.Length);
        Debug.Print("From ImplementsIDerivedOne: {0} properties", propsFromImplementsIDerivedOne .Length );
    }
}
```

Result:
From IBaseOne: 1 properties
From IDerivedOne: 1 properties
From ImplementsIDerivedOne: 2 properties

Why IDerivedOne only shows 1 property?

thank you

Enrique

Answer (score 5):

That's because interfaces do not "derive" from one another; think of them as contracts that implementing classes must honor. Therefore, when you have this:

```
interface IFoo : IBar { }
```

it does not mean that `IFoo` itself has the same members that `IBar` does. It means that *any implementers of `IFoo` also take on the responsibility of implementing `IBar`*. The distinction might sound like fine print when viewed from the implementer's perspective, but it does make a very important difference to the type system.

If you want specifically to find out *which properties must be defined by an implementor of `IDerivedOne`* instead of *which properties `IDerivedOne` declares* you will have to reflect on `IDerivedOne`, find its "base" interfaces and recursively enumerate their members.